# Foreign Key to get many instances of a class

Tags: python, django, key

So, this is what my code looks like right now:

[image]

And when I click on the products I would ideally like to get this:

[image]

So, right now my code is only allowing me to get one product, but I would like the option of adding unlimited amount of products.

Here's my code:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('VendorProfile')
    dollar_amount = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Price')


class Product(models.Model):
   products = models.CharField(max_length=256)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return self.products
```

How can I do this? Or, rather, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ManyToManyField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) instead of a ForeignKey.

Comment: I just did this and it gave me an error "'PurchaseOrderAdmin.list_display[0]', 'product' is a ManyToManyField which is not supported." However, in admin.py, when I take out 'product' in list_display it compiles. How can I include a many-to-many field in list_display?

Comment: The documentation on `list_display` is quite clear: "`ManyToManyField` fields aren’t supported, because that would entail executing a separate SQL statement for each row in the table. If you want to do this nonetheless, give your model a custom method, and add that method’s name to `list_display`. (See below for more on custom methods in `list_display`.)" http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display